# Searching for data in XML file with Nokogiri in Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, xpath, nokogiri

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" targetNamespace="NewDataSet" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
  <xsd:element name="table">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="d_codigo" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="5" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="d_asenta" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="60" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="d_tipo_asenta" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="40" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="D_mnpio" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="d_estado" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="35" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="d_ciudad" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="d_CP" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="5" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="c_estado" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="2" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="c_oficina" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="5" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="c_CP" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="5" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="c_tipo_asenta" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="2" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="c_mnpio" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="3" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="id_asenta_cpcons" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="4" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="d_zona" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="40" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="c_cve_ciudad" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="3082" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth">
              <xsd:maxLength value="2" />
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<NewDataSet>
  <table xmlns="NewDataSet">
    <d_codigo>98000</d_codigo>
    <d_asenta>Zacatecas Centro</d_asenta>
    <d_tipo_asenta>Colonia</d_tipo_asenta>
    <D_mnpio>Zacatecas</D_mnpio>
    <d_estado>Zacatecas</d_estado>
    <d_ciudad>Zacatecas</d_ciudad>
    <d_CP>98001</d_CP>
    <c_estado>32</c_estado>
    <c_oficina>98001</c_oficina>
    <c_CP/>
    <c_tipo_asenta>09</c_tipo_asenta>
    <c_mnpio>056</c_mnpio>
    <id_asenta_cpcons>0001</id_asenta_cpcons>
    <d_zona>Urbano</d_zona>
    <c_cve_ciudad>03</c_cve_ciudad>
  </table>
  <!-- More elements table like the one above continue -->
</NewDataSet>
```

I am trying to search for all the values in the tag "d_CP" using Nokogiri for a Rails app. This is a part of the file including one element.

Currently, I am trying.

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(path_to_file), nil, 'UTF-8')
```

Which succesfully parses the file but when I try [B]:

```
puts @doc.xpath("//d_CP")
```

The output in the Rails console is:

```
nil
```

The same happens when I try with "table".
When I try

```
puts @doc.xpath("//NewDataSet")
```

it prints the whole file.

What I am doing wrong in [B] ?

Comment: Can you add the complete structure of your file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution but I let the answer for anybody has the same problem. Actually this XML file uses namespaces which I think is not necessary as there are no collisions. In xpath you have to specify that namespace with:

```
@doc.xpath('//xmlns:d_CP', 'xmlns' => 'NewDataSet')
```

Another solutions is to remove the namespaces with:

```
@doc.remove_namespaces!
```

Then use xpath normally.